Pterodactyl - PANEL can't reach WINGS (cURL error 28)
I have installed Ubuntuserver 22.04.4 on a PC in a network. I then installed Pterodactyl with wings and the panel. As I am on a different network, I created port shares for SSH (22) on the server's network and the following: 443, 8080, 80, 2022. After installing Pterodactyl, I went to the website (panel.example.com) to log in to the panel and that worked. Then I created a location to create a node. I created the node with all the required information (screenshot1) node settings, but the node does not get a connection (screenshot2/3).node status node status2
I then had a look and with the command:
tail -n 1000 /var/www/pterodactyl/storage/logs/laravel-$(date +%F).log | grep "\[$(date +%Y)"
I got the following error message:
[2024-07-10 19:08:00] production.WARNING: GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 28: Failed to connect to node.example.com port 8080 after 3753 ms: Connection timed out (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://node.example.com:8080/api/system in /var/www/pterodactyl/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php:210
panel.example.com / node.example.com are only example addresses to avoid publishing my personal domains.
i have already tried to reset the whole server (had ubuntu 24.04 before)
I have also deleted all port shares and restored them again.
i have also tried restarting wings, but everything looks fine (i think).
i've also tried a few other things, but i'm not quite sure what they all were anymore
